# HTTP Error 500 when trying to execucute INSERT INTO sql query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm fairly new to php and SQL and just can't figure out the problem. Note that this is a school project, therefore the vulnerability to SQL Injections and saving the blank passwords are nothing to worry about.

After the User filled out the Login-form, he's redirected to this page:

```
[Some html]
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    ConnectSQL();
}
//Retrieve POSTed Login information
$Username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['RegUsername']);
$Email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['RegEmail']);
$Password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['RegPassword']);

function ConnectSQL() {     
    // SQL Server Extension Sample Code:
    // (ConnectionInfo, obviously it's there in the real file)
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    // PHP Data Objects(PDO) Sample Code:
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:server = tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433; Database = userdb', 'arechon', '{NotTheRealPassword}');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Successfully connected to SQL Server and DB";
            Register();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print('Error connecting to SQL Server.');
        die(print_r($e));
    }
}

function Register($Username, $Email, $Password) {
        $regquery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Users (Username, Email, Password) VALUES ('UsernameTest', 'EmailTest', 'PasswordTest')";
        $conn->query($regquery);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.open("http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/Login.html", "_self");</script>';
```

The Code always seems to stop at `$conn->query($regquery);` and doesn't return any error messages. Sometimes it just stops, when I slightly modify the Code (e.g. replacing `$conn->query($regquery);` with `$conn->exec($regquery);` or using " instead of ') I get a HTTP500 error.

I found some similiar questions here on stackoverflow as well as on other plattforms, but none of the provided answers could solve this error. Note that I use SQL and NOT MySQL (though it wouldn't be a lot of work to change that if you think that could solve my problem).

Comment: What does the server says ? you probably have the server configured in the way that it doesn't show you the error so look in the logs or activate the error display.

Comment: Please post your actual code with credentials removed and no inline comments. `Register();` isn't passing any values, but your query isnt using any..

Comment: check your logs

Comment: btw; `htmlspecialchars()` doesn't safeguard against sql injections, if that's what you're hoping to do; that's mostly used for display purposes and to safeguard against XSS attacks; two different animals here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was told to do this and since I didn't have any idea of php before, I just did it.

Comment: @0x1gene I checked the most recent log, but tbh I have no idea what all of that means. Most of it is related to javascript, but I'll upload it anyway. Maybe you can spot something important in there? [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cqxjxxny5rlw7rv/AACB6ZfXQ9FfOKLw06t2ccDha?dl=0) are the log files.